# Unexpected result when comparing value received from socket to integer

Tags: python, sockets

I'm receiving data from the socket, then saving one of its elements as `recentnumb`.

When I print it just before the `if` statement it correctly prints that it's 0. Unfortunately my `if` statement always behaves as if `recentnumb` were different than 0, no matter how I modify the expression. Could someone explain to me why my `if` statement does not see `recentnumb` as 0?

```
r = wrappedSocket.recv(1024)
v = r.split()
recentnumb = v[1]

print recentnumb

if recentnumb != 0:
    Dothis()
else:
    OrDothis()
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? Considering the `r.split()` it appears that `recentnumb` is either `str` or `bytes`, not `int`. On python 2, `str` would never equal 0. On python 3 you get an error.

Comment: The docs state `socket.recv()` "return value is a string representing the data received", you might try `int(v[1])`

Comment: What format is that list? TCP is a streaming protocol, not a messaging protocol. There is no guarantee that a single `recv` gets exactly what was written in a single `send`.

Comment: @downshift - that's true in python 2. In 3, its `bytes`. OP uses the python 3 form of print, but this code would raise an exception in python 3. Best we hear from the source! Your suggestion will work either way of course... assuming that the `recv` really got the full list.

Comment: @tdelaney its Python 2 and You was right. I just formatted recentnumb to int and now everything works. Thank You

Comment: Credit for the solution goes to @downshift! BTW, when using print to figure out what's going on, I like to do `print(repr(recentnumb))`. Otherwise its hard to tell the difference between strings and ints.

Answer (score 0):

The docs state `socket.recv()` "return value is a string representing
the data received", you might try `int(v[1])`.